# How to use MEF and dlls embeded resources in a dll project c#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mef

For an important project i have to use MEF to build a large assembly. The assembly must turn on a web server.

My question is how can i load and add the embed dlls to my project using MEF ?
Before i have used this approach which works :

```
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"R:\DNN\Extensions", "*.dll"));

        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        try
        {
            container.ComposeParts(this);
        }
        catch (CompositionException compositionException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(compositionException.ToString());
        }
```

But with this solution is very dificult to mantain ! I can not update the dlls in the Extansions folder when they are in use.

The only way is to restart the DNN cms or charge the updated dlls in a new folder ExtensionsBis.

I have to find a new solution to compose the project with the extarnal dlls. I have try this solution with embeded dlls :

```
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        var resourceNames = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
        foreach (var resourceName in resourceNames)
        {
            using (var stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                if (stream == null) continue;
                var ba = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
                stream.Read(ba, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.Load(ba)));
            }
        }
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        try
        {
            container.ComposeParts(this);
        }
        catch (CompositionException compositionException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(compositionException.ToString());
        }
```

The dlls are loaded and added in the catalog, I have no exception at the composition.

But, when I try to execute the exported functions or acces the class at runtime i have an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

The catalog.catalogs.count give the rite number of charged dlls, but the MEF composition seems to fail somewhere.

Is it posible to load MEF dlls plugins that way ?
What is the best practice to use MEF inside a dll ?

Thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to monitor the folder where your plugins are stored. Configure an event handler for the Created event and load the library using your initial code block.